# Как данные из одного столбца использовать в другом?

Tags: sqlite3

id автоинкримент, нужно, чтобы значение следующего за ним столбца формировалось из его значения:

```
query('INSERT INTO `sitys` VALUES (:id, SUBSTR("0000" || :id, -4, 4), :title. :text');
```

То есть получается, если id = 1, то следующий столбец = 0001

Как сделать такое?

Вот так работает, но это всё коряво, хотелось бы както поизящнее, в одну команду что ли

```
query('INSERT INTO `sisys` VALUES (:id, NULL, :title, :text)');
query('UPDATE `sisys` SET number = substr("0000" || id, -4, 4)');
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный код из своего примера.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35060424/6750422

Comment: [Generated Columns](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, а вы не могли бы показать на моём примере? Я тупая в этих запросах вообще, а там всё так заумно… :)

Comment: Ну, либо если там есть триггеры, то триггером )

Comment: @CrazyElf, триггеры вроде бы есть, но для меня они и вовсе ребус :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может Вам подойдет вычисляемый столбец в таблице?  Пример:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(Id INTEGER
            , SValue TEXT 
            , GValue TEXT  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr('000'||Id,length(Id),4))STORED
                );
insert into `t1`(Id,SValue) VALUES(1,'test1');
insert into `t1`(Id,SValue) VALUES(10,'test10');
insert into `t1`(Id,SValue) VALUES(100,'test100');
select * from t1;
```

Результат

| Id | SValue | GValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 0001 |
| 10 | test10 | 0010 |
| 100 | test100 | 0100 |

Comment: вы знаете, да, видимо то, что нужно. Только я не пойму как это в запросе моём применить. А вот это `GENERATED ALWAYS AS substr('000'||Id,length(Id),4))STORED` наверное нужно чтобы было  при создании таблицы?

Comment: Да, свойство GENERATED ALWAYS нужно в описании таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо большое!